# How do I automate the width of a container / parent after rotating a text?

Tags: html, css, web, text-rotation

When I rotate a text element inside a div / container by 90 degrees, the parent container has the same width as the length of the text despite the text being rotated.

So for example:
Suppose that the text is a 200 x 10. After rotation, it becomes a 10 x 200. But the container stays 200 x 10 as opposed to 10 x 200.

How can I automate the width of the container so that it is the height of the unrotated text when the text is rotated?

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="to_rotate"> Hello, rotate me! </span>
</div>

.to_rotate {
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the rotate class to the container?

Comment: @Riz-waan Hello, no it can't. I'm putting the container in a grid. The grid columns fluctuate in accordance with the elements. So if the container gets smaller, so does the grid.

Comment: @Riz-waan also I just tried it and the for some reason the container now has the height of the grid column

Comment: CSS `transform` does not change how an element's parent sees that element. Regardless of what `transform` you apply, the parent will always see it as though no `transform` was applied.

Comment: @Ouroborus understood that. so how can i apply it so that the parent does see a transformation?

Comment: you can use writing-mode like here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54392143/8620333