# Vertical button with a container that expands to button's full height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a vertical button inside a div element, but I can't get the div's height to fill the remaining space. 
I flipped the button using transform and I'm using Bulma for the layout. Here's the outline of my code:

```css
.column {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#" class="button">SHOW OPTIONS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure what I can do here to fix this and make it responsive? I know I can always use a fixed height, but is there any way I could do it differently, so it expands with the content? Can someone please take a look and let me know if you have any suggestions? I don't even have to use transform, that just seemed like a logical option.

Thank you!

Comment: you can probably consider `writing-mode` (related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54392143/8620333)

Comment: Thank you, that could possibly work!

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason, you can't use the `writing-mode` property, here is an alternative solution:

```css
.column {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
}

.so55562898-outer {
  display: inline-block;
}

.so55562898-inner {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding-top: calc(100% - 36px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="so55562898-outer">
        <div class="so55562898-inner">
          <a href="#" class="button">SHOW OPTIONS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note that this solution requires to know the height of the button (in this case: **36px**).

Answer (score -2):

I hope it works for you

```css
.column1 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: gray;
  display: block;
padding: 3.40rem;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column1">
    <a href="#" class="button">SHOW OPTIONS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do that since I need to use Bulma and its layout. So the class needs to remain.